# Biting and fur pulling while playing

Tags: dogs, behavior, biting, play

I dog-sit a 7 year old Labradoodle. He loves to play with our neighbors dog and they have gotten along great until recently. Our dog recently was neutered and since that time he has been biting our neighbors dog. At first we thought it was just play biting until yesterday when he started pulling out her fur. Our dog is a standard size and our neighbors is a miniature sheep dog.

Their dog was always the dominate one, which was always fine with our dog. It seems things have changed now and at times their dog seems afraid of our dog. How can I stop this behavior so they can become friends again?

Answer (score 2):

You could redirect your dog whenever he tries to bite or when you first see the bad behavior occurring.  So for example when your dog attempts to bite your neighbors dog you could call your dog with a treat or redirect your dog with their favorite toy, make your pet sit, or lie down and continually do that so your dog begins to do it less.  If that doesnʻt work, dog classes could help. Not sure if this will help.